# Is there a tangible benefit to using "self" outside of closures?

Tags: ios, swift, self

I have noticed a few people in the industry will use the *self* keyword even when not explicitly required (i.e. outside of closures).

**Example:**

```
import UIKit
import MapView
import CoreLocation

class viewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationDelegate {

    let mapView = MKMapView()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView.delegate = self
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
}
```

Is there a tangible benefit to this, runtime-wise? Or is this purely a stylistic choice?

Comment: Stylistic choice that comes from ObjectiveC where this was necessary.

Comment: As you've coded? Not really. But if your `init` (or other function) takes a **named** input parameter (say in your code, `desiredAccuracy`), sure. It's self documenting code. PLEASE NOTE: Many will disagree with this, as it's not "Swifty". And... thinking it through, I guess everything I just stated **is** stylistic.

Comment: I do it because for a couple of reasons; Habit from Objective-C and also it shows me (and anyone else that looks at my code) that I am accessing a property, not a local variable; ie. this action may have consequences (or be influenced by events) outside of the current context.  It can also be required for disambiguation where there is both a property and a local variable with the same name

Comment: it is the same as this in Java and self in Objective-C, but with Swift, self is only require when you call a property or method from a closure or to differentiate property names inside your code. So you can use almost all of your class components safely without using self unless you are making the call from a closure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is.

In the examples you provided it makes no difference, it's purely a style choice. Some people might like it since it explicitly tells you you're modifying `self`, personally I think it looks cleaner without.

Where it matters is when you have a local variable with the same name. Let's say you have a class that has a `var count: Int` property. Then, in one of your methods, you declare a new variable with the same name.

The local variable will be used whenever you type `count`, so if you want to modify or read the object's variable, you'll need to use `self`.

Some examples where it makes a difference:

```
guard let count = calculateCount() as? Int else { return }
self.count = count

init(count: Int) {
  self.count = count
}

func updateCount(_ count: Int) {
  self.count = count
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are some benefits.

- Using keywords like `self` or `init` or `Swift` prevent Xcode from                                                      ambiguity of overloads
- make it compile faster
- brings autocomplete suggestions faster;

that's it! Even though you use them explicitly, the compiler removes them from compiled code for compressing reasons. But it is **not preferred**! It's all about the scope of variables and functions.

Take a look at this example:

```
let name = "global variable"
class MyClass {
    let name = "object variable"

    func testScopes() {
        let name = "function local variable"
        print(name) //prints: function local variable
        print(self.name) //prints: object variable
        print(MyProject.name) // prints: global variable
    }
}

let myObject = MyClass()
myObject.testScopes()
```

Here are three variables with three different valid scopes. You can refer to each one you need differently.
Swift community suggested:

> For conciseness, avoid using **self** since Swift does not require it to access an object's properties or invoke its methods.
>
> Use **self** only when required by the compiler (in **@escaping closures**, or
>   in **initializers** to disambiguate properties from arguments). In other
>   words, if it compiles **without self** then omit it.

But it's ultimately up to you and your company's code style guide.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the practical reason where it is required when there is a local variable or parameter with the same name, I do it because for a couple of reasons:

- Habit from Objective-C
- It explicitly shows me (and anyone else that looks at my code) that I am accessing a property, not a local variable; ie. this action may have consequences (or be influenced by events) outside of the current context.

Comment: A note regarding the second bullet - clear code doesn't need `self`, one should be able to tell from the context if it's dealing with a property or a local var (i.e. clear naming).

Comment: Naming wont help a lot but the same thing `self.` is doing for you can be just setup in Xcode as a different font or color.

Answer (score 0):

My personal convention is to only use `self` in closures. For a few reasons.

1. It tells me, as a developer, that we are explicitly in a closure, because `self` is required.
2. `self` is very important in closures, and lets us know of possible retain cycles and memory leaks when we capture `self` strongly.
3. It is redundant when not in a closure, when there are not multiple variables of the same name inside the same or different scopes.

One thing I will say, when coding, using `self.` is a quick way to see what's available in the class or struct we are in. However, I will remove it after I find what I need.